Getting error while using paginationpagesize in ag grid 30.0.2
Here I am adding paginationPageSizeSelector in ag grid version 30.0.2 but getting this error using ag-grid angular
Error:

         <ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-alpine"  
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
            [pagination]="true"
            [paginationPageSize]="pageSize" 
            [paginationPageSizeSelector]="[10,20,30]"
            [rowHeight]="45"
            [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
            [rowData]="rowData" 
            [animateRows]="true" 
            [rowModelType]="rowModelType"
            (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
            (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)" 
            [cacheBlockSize]="cacheBlockSize"
            [enableRangeSelection]="true">
         </ag-grid-angular>

I tried giving the size of array like [10,20,30] as manually and by variable still getting the error

Try removing the quotes around the array i.e [paginationPageSizeSelector]=[10,20,30]

when you received an error similar to "czn bind to ... since is not a property..if ... is a component be sure.." generally it's because you have not import the "Module" where the component is defined. If your'e using "standalone" components add the Module to the imports array of the component. If you're using Modules, add the Module to the imports array of the module where is declared the component.

I faced the same issue , you can upgrade it to higher version it will go. I upgraded to 31
